# C# CMD Ping timestamp

Tags: c#, ping

I'm trying to figure out how to get work ping timestamp in C#

I tryed also  System.DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") but its sayng in program wrong host.

At the moment ping showing

**Form design:**

[image]

**I tried to use this code:**

```
ping -t 127.0.0.1|cmd /q /v /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!date! !time! !data!)&ping -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul"
```

**My code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;

namespace PingProgramm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Thread th;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            th = new Thread(thread1);
            th.Start();
        }

        public void thread1()
        {
            try
            {
                string command = "/c ping -t " + textBox1.Text + "|cmd /q /v /c (pause&pause)>nul & for /l %a in () do (set /p " + "data" + '=' + " && echo(!date! !time! !data!)&ping -n 2" + textBox1.Text + ">nul";
                ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD", command);
                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);
                proc.Start();
                proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
                proc.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //if an error occurs with in the try block, it will handled here.
            }
        }
        void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (stop)
            {
                var proc = (Process)sender;

                stop = false; // allows you to spawn a new thread after stopping the first
                proc.SynchronizingObject = this; // puts the form in charge of async communication
                proc.Kill(); // terminates the thread
                proc.WaitForExit(); // thread is killed asynchronously, so this goes here.

            }
            if (e.Data != null)
            {
                string newLine = e.Data.Trim() + Environment.NewLine;
                MethodInvoker append = () => {
                    richTextBox1.Text += newLine;
                    if (checkBox1.Checked)
                    {
                        WriteLog(newLine);
                    }
                };
                richTextBox1.BeginInvoke(append);
            }
        }
        bool firstTime = true;
        private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (firstTime)
            {
                firstTime = false;
                textBox1.Clear();
            }
        }

        bool stop = false;
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stop = true;
        }

        public static void WriteLog(string strLog)
        {
            StreamWriter log;
            FileStream fileStream = null;
            DirectoryInfo logDirInfo = null;
            FileInfo logFileInfo;

            string logFilePath = "C:\\Logid\\";
            logFilePath = logFilePath + "Log-" + System.DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "." + "txt";
            logFileInfo = new FileInfo(logFilePath);
            logDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(logFileInfo.DirectoryName);
            if (!logDirInfo.Exists) logDirInfo.Create();
            if (!logFileInfo.Exists)
            {
                fileStream = logFileInfo.Create();
            }
            else
            {
                fileStream = new FileStream(logFilePath, FileMode.Append);
            }
            log = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
            log.WriteLine(strLog);
            log.Close();
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I debugged it but it's not saying any error or something that.

Comment: Surely if you ping natively (Ping.Send()) you can easily format it however you like

Answer (score 0):

You see no error because the thread in which your command is executed swallows the exception.

```
    public void thread1()
    {
        try
        {
            string command = "/c ping -t " + textBox1.Text + "|cmd /q /v /c (pause&pause)>nul & for /l %a in () do (set /p " + "data" + '=' + " && echo(!date! !time! !data!)&ping -n 2" + textBox1.Text + ">nul";
            ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD", command);
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);
            proc.ErrorDataReceived+= new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_ErrorDataReceived); // add error output
            proc.Start();
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            proc.BeginErrorReadLine(); // begin read error output
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) // add ex here so you can look into it.
        {   // <== Breakpoint here
            //if an error occurs with in the try block, it will handled here.
        }
    }
```

There are multiple ways to debug this.

1. Make a breakpoint in the line commeted above.
2. Enable All Exceptions by go to "Debug->Exception Settings" and then check Common Language Runtime Exceptions until it is completely checked.
3. Also Process offers ErrorDataReceived which you should check.

Comment: Error CS0103 The name 'proc_ErrorDataReceived' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @KLDesigns that's because you haven't created it yet

Comment: `void proc_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received from standard error: " + e.Data);
        }`

Comment: But ping code still not working `string command = "/c ping -t " + textBox1.Text + "|cmd /q /v /c (pause&pause)>nul & for /l %a in () do (set /p " + "data" + '=' + " && echo(!date! !time! !data!)&ping -n 2" + textBox1.Text + ">nul";`